# How to get a specific index of a query in Firestore using Node.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to get a random document from a Firestore collection using node.js. My random index is weighted so that those documents closer to the 0 index have a greater chance of selection. I want to order the query by 'Points' and then only get the document at the index specified.

At first I used this :

```
random = "My random Logic"
let questionsRef = db.collection('Collection Name')
                return questionsRef.where('Points', '>=', 0).orderBy('Points').limit(random).get()
```

This returned a set of documents.

So my next attempt was to use the following

```
random = "My random Logic"
let questionsRef = db.collection('Collection Name')
                return questionsRef.where('Points', '>=', 0).orderBy('Points').limit(random).limitToLast(1).get()
```

Unfortunately no matter the random number generated I only get the document with the highest Point count.

Any suggestions on how to fix the query?